# TimeZone with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have a javascript script which takes in date, lat, long, timeZone

```
var times = Times.getTimes(date, [40.5700710, -74.3664700], -5);
```

I get the date from a date picker which looks like this

```
var date = new Date($(".ui-datepicker-month",$(this).parents()).text()+ " " + $(this).text() +","+$(".ui-datepicker-year",$(this).parents()).text());
```

so is there a way I can get correct timeZone with dst.

"date" returns Tue Nov 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

which is correct...

Comment: check this, http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: 1) `-5` is an offset, not a time zone.  Where did it come from?  Read "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) 2) You've not been clear about how lat/lon is relevant - do you want the time zone for that location?  3) it's not clear what exactly is in the string you're passing in to the `Date` constructor.  Instead of showing all the jquery and picker stuff, just show an example string.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you're even looking for.  You ask for "correct timeZone with dst" - what do you mean by that? Please show an example of the expected output.  You did show your `date` variable, but it's not clear that that is output - it looks like it's an input, as part of the `times` array that you receive.

Comment: im sorry I want the offset. as -5 but using date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; return 5 not -5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [getTimezoneOffset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) method of *Date* object. It returns difference (in minutes) between UTC and the local time. In your case it will return 300.

Comment: I believe it returns `300`, not `-300`.